# Multi Level Accordion Like Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

Trying to create a multi level accordion like navigation menu using `jquery`. I got this from a post and i was able to do it but the challenge is the `sub-sub-items` are not getting displayed when clicked on it.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/66kJs/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:viod(0)">Item 2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Sub Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Sub Item 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Sub Item 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Sub Item 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:viod(0)">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:viod(0)">Item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:viod(0)">Item 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.sidebar > ul > li > a').click(function(ev) {
    $('.sidebar .sub-menu, .sub-menu .sub-sub-menu').stop().slideUp();
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Please help me in getting this fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selectors are bit too specific, same with the classes in the html.

No need to use `sub-sub-menu`, just keep all sub menus as `sub-menu`, no matter how nested they are.

Also, loosen up the selector, don't use the child selector `>`.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66kJs/4/ (click Item 2, then Sub Item 1)

Update: forgot about the accordion affect! made the fix
Update: removed the `stop()` - if interacting during animation, it would leave artifacts of the previous state of elements

Comment: @zamnuts- Thanks for the reply. But now i lost the accordion like effect. I'm looking out with a accordion effect. I was able to do the what's the fiddle right now. Help me in make it like a accordion one. And when i click on a `sub-item` it's getting collapsed.

Comment: Done as you wished. I wanted to know more about jquery. Any thing you'd like to help?

Comment: Please look at the height when you click the `sub-sub-menu`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41763/discussion-between-zamnuts-and-user2549787)